# Host with online server(Linux)

Tags: linux, virtualhost

I purchased a server with ubuntu server.
Is it possible to create virtualhosts and connect them to a public domain to browse them?

Thank you,
Best regards,

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Read the documentation of your favourite webserver software and ask questions once you encounter concrete problems.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

simple short answer as the question only state if it's possible

##Answer

#Yes it's possible.

since nothing has been more asked please accept the answer and i
please discuss first instead of down voted